# Quick access to recurrent searches in Sublime Text

Tags: search, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a regex expression that I use regularly to find specific lines in my codebase.
Let's say the expression is

```
\s*<search keyword> = myClass(.*)
```

with `<search keyword>` being the part of the regex that changes depending of the search.

**How can I make entering such a search as fast as possible in ST3?**

I tried using [snippets](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/snippets.html) that at first sight seem to fill my need as they enable to set the location where the text editing will be resumed, so I could just type `<snippet alias><TAB><search keyword>` in *Find:* field to trigger the search.
Alas no, snippets are disabled in search fields (only accessible in main text window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use snippets in search bar, for example:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
\s*$1 = myClass(.*)
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>search</tabTrigger>
<description>Search snippet</description>
</snippet>
```

BUT you can only expand them with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Tab key for snippet expansion does not work in search field.

Btw: This works for me in Sublime Text 2. But it should work in Sublime Text 3 too

Comment: I would accept that answer if it prompted me to enter my <search keyword> and use it to build the final regex before executing it.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that there was a placeholder in the regex. I've rewritten my answer with easier solution. Please give it a try

Comment: Nah, the *tabTrigger* doesn't work : nothing happens when pressing `CTRL+Space` in search bar (but if I type "search"+`TAB` in the file buffer it uses the snippet).

Comment: Well that's weird. Just tried it on Sublime Text 3 and it works for me too. Are you using Linux by any chance? I had to explicitly bind auto complete to CTRL space in order for it to work on linux properly

Comment: Yep Ubuntu! ok auto-complete is binded now. But whatever I type in "find" field when I type `Ctrl+space` it prints "No available completion" in the status bar.

Comment: Are you using correct tab trigger? Type your tab trigger in the search field and hit ctrl + space then. Also check if your snippet is not bound to specific filetype only.